# Joomla article structure

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I was a newbie in Joomla and using the latest version to create my website. I want to create news page (list of article). I'm using module ([external plugin](http://www.joomlahill.com/downloads/11-modules/21-featured-categories)) to listing all the article. But I'm not understand the structure to create the pages.

I got a menu like this:

- Home
- Latest News (link to single article with category 'Latest News')

This is my category:

- Home
- Latest News

  - News (every new article will be under this category)
  - Events

Then I display all the article inside **Latest News** page except the page I leave as blank because I using module to display the list. The URL will be like this **mywebsitename/latest-news**.

The problem is when I click one of the article to show full details of the article. The URL will be like **mywebsitename/latest-news/11-home/latest-news/news/articleName**. So how I need to do to structure the URL even my breadcrumb to be like this

> mywebsitename / Latest News / News / article name

Even the module also display inside the article page. I only set this module under latest news page only. Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use category blog menu type for news? No need for external plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you just began, restart your project. If you want to build up a site, first check whether there are any core functions for your usage or not. If it can be done through them, do it like that, as this is better for updating your site. (Maybe your plugin will not be supported later on...)

Then restart by building up your site: 
Category - Article - Menu 
Firstly, create the categories you wish. For example, you want the category "News" where you put news articles and a category "Events" where you put articles about your events.
Secondly create some articles for your category. You can use the "read-more" to preview your articles in your blog.
Last, create the menu. You can use a category blog and it's options to show your articles the way you want.